# Set default page like home page while loading application

Tags: angular

Hi I have an issue that when application was loaded I want to change **default page** (like loading home page of the application to other some page) ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to your desired route, in ngOnInit() hook in starting of your application (i.e. root component)